# How to make this NSURLConnection work?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *post = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];        
for (TestVariable *testVariable in variables)
    {
        NSData *testVariable=[self getJSONTestVariable:testVariable];
        NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:maintenanceData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [post setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [post setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [post addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [post addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [post setHTTPBody: [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];               TestVariableDelegate *sjd= [TestVariableDelegate alloc];
       NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:post delegate:sjd];
       [connection start];
    }
```

The issue I have with this code is that just one of the 2-3-100 elements I am trying to send gets sent and I'm not sure how to solve the issue.

The implementation of the delegate is pretty basic, it just processes the response in a way and saves it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right and you want to make a request for each testVariable, you should put the `NSMutableURLRequest` definition into the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: put a 10 second interval between the requests, just to see if there is any change in his behavior.